# I want to work in a query a large database

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to optimize database this query in large database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999134/how-to-optimize-database-this-query-in-large-database)

```
SELECT id FROM `user_tmp` 
WHERE  `code` = '9s5xs1sy' 
  AND  `go` NOT REGEXP 'http://www.xxxx.com/aflam/|http://xx.com|http://www.xxxxx.com/aflam/|http://www.xxxxxx.com/v/|http://www.xxxxxx.com/vb/'  
  AND check='done'  
  AND  `dataip` <1319992460
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 50
```

MySQL returns:

> Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 50 total, Query took 7.3102 sec) [id: 2622270 - 2602288]

if i remove

```
AND `dataip` <1319992460
```

MySQL returns

> Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 50 total, Query took 0.0859 sec) [id: 3637556 - 3627005]

and if no data, MySQL returns

> MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 21.7332 sec )

I want the correct way to do the query

thanx

Comment: OK... so what's the question?

Comment: What is your question? 
I guess you want an index on dataip?

Comment: -1 no clue what you are asking or doing.

Comment: I want the correct way to do the query

Comment: Please help me I am new in programming i wont best way to do the query

Comment: Next time, please update your original question instead of asking a new one if you have more information to add.

Answer (score 0):

You should have correct index on `dataip` column and others you're using in this current query.

Comment: I want the correct way to query without work many Query took

Comment: @10neen it's exactly what you should do: add/modify index

Comment: How did that Please explain ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe step 1 should be to run `EXPLAIN` on your query to see which indexes (if any) it is using for the query.

I'd recommend starting here: [Optimizing Queries with EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html).

Read that section, try running `EXPLAIN` on your query and then come back with the output in a format that we can understand -- as well as with what you might think it means.

Best of luck.

Comment: What is the solution to the query work properly without a bad query on the server
Please help me I am new in programming
thanx

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is. Is it the query takes too long? Is it that you are getting incorrect data?

Comment: yes query takes too long i wont best way to selvo that